# Javascript Fetch Not passing Cookies in the Request Headers, even with 'same-origin' credentials

Tags: javascript, cookies, fetch, credentials

I am attempting to make a Fetch request with Javascript using:
credentials: 'same-origin'
method: 'GET'

But in the fetch request I am unable to pass a client (browser) cookie in the request headers. I know that the issue is not a cors issue as that was corrected on both the client and server.

In the Header it looks like all other values are correct except that there is no cookie in the fetch request.

Answer (score 1):

Since you had to correct a CORS issue, you must be making a cross-origin request.

That means it **isn't** a `same-origin` request and you need to use `include` not `same-origin`.

Note that the cookies sent will be the ones associated with the origin you are making the request **to**, not from.